# How to remove duplicate files in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have 500 files in a directory and some of them are duplicates. They are called prime-0.png to prime-499.png.  I can see they are duplicated by running md5sum for example on them.

> How can I delete the duplicate files so I am left with only one copy
>   of each?

```
md5sum prime-*
```

gives me:

```
ed8c994d608ba2fde59e6a08c65bcc1f  prime-0.png
e7667b2c92359d23cd1cd251e54b41ba  prime-100.png
0afc9b57206cde58ff609a6476bde7a6  prime-101.png
[...]
```

I can see how many are duplicated by doing:

```
md5sum prime-* |cut -f1 -d\ |sort|uniq -c|sort -rn|less
```

which gives me:

```
5 f905fde6abfbcbb00e079dcd4ecacbb7
3 efcdd042802fc0efc6d9fdf164df4e20
3 ed5a46d250c85809b57ee96385f655d2
3 c4cff53df13b87381b2c06538c339790
[...]
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Cyrus I added my attempts to get a handle on the problem.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful.I retracted my closevote and downvote.

Comment: Just use `fdupes`, the tool that implements the same logic but more robustly

Comment: [linux dedup files command line](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+dedup+files+command+line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is only suitable for file names without line breaks.

`awk` outputs duplicates in first column:

```
md5sum prime-* | awk 'n[$1]++' | cut -d " " -f 3- | xargs -I {} echo rm {}
```

If output looks fine, remove `echo`.

---

From `man xargs`:

> `-I replace-str`: Replace occurrences of `replace-str` in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input. Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items;

Comment: nitpick: what if there is a filename that contains a line break?

Comment: Then it wouldn't work. Hence the `echo`, to check it in advance.

Comment: `md5sum` (and `shasum`, `sha224sum`, `sha384sum`, `sha512sum`, too) then behaves surprisingly in this case, because It then precedes the checksum with a backslash and that already makes everything collapse.

Comment: `...sum` programs can produce null delimited output, GNU `Awk` can probably as well deal with null delimited records. Then it could deal with special file names.

Comment: Could you explain the -I {} and the final {} please?

Answer (score 3):

Using an associative array, which requires bash >4.0:

```
declare -A a

for f in prime-*; do
  f_md5=$(md5sum <"$f" | cut -c-32)
  if [ -n "${a[$f_md5]- }" ]; then
    a[$f_md5]=
  else
    rm -- "$f"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Great to see a pure bash coding answer.

Comment: What does `declare -A a`  do?

Comment: @Anush it declares that `a` is an associative array, without it, `${a[$f_md5]- }` doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 1):

Compare no more then characters in md5sum when searching for a duplicate with `uniq -D`. Then join the list with one file per duplicates group with `uniq -d`.

```
# the input file
# files 102-105 are to be removed
cat <<EOF |
ed8c994d608ba2fde59e6a08c65bcc1f  prime-0.png
e7667b2c92359d23cd1cd251e54b41ba  prime-100.png
0afc9b57206cde58ff609a6476bde7a6  prime-101.png
0afc9b57206cde58ff609a6476bde7a6  prime-102.png
0afc9b57206cde58ff609a6476bde7a6  prime-103.png
0afc9b57206cde58ff609a6476bde7a6  prime-104.png
e7667b2c92359d23cd1cd251e54b41ba  prime-105.png
EOF
# sort with md5sums
# save to temporary file
sort -t' ' -k1 > tmp1

# we print all duplicates with first uniq
# and print only one duplicate per group with second group
# then we find elements in the first stream not in the second
comm -23 <(uniq -w32 -D tmp1) <(uniq -w32 -d tmp1) |
# extract the filename
cut -d' ' -f3
```

will output:

```
prime-102.png
prime-103.png
prime-104.png
prime-105.png
```

Live version at [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/LeadingCommonApplication).

The magic constant `32` is the length of characters of md5sum, ie. the output of `echo -n '0afc9b57206cde58ff609a6476bde7a6' | wc -c`.